# Google Play Game Service: How can I implements custom UI to achievements and leaderboards

Tags: android

I'm developing android game app using Google Play Game Services. I made my app using MainActivity(extends BaseGameActivity) and various fragments. I want to implement custom UI to achievements and leaderboards. How can I do it? I can't find relevant docs on developers site.